# How to align a text bounding box with a pyplot.Rectangle?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to put a text with its bounding box exactly above another bounding box (a `pyplot.Rectangle` with `fill=False`).

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

FIGSIZE = (8, 8)
LINEWIDTH = 3
FONTSIZE = 12
X_MIN, Y_MIN = 68, 93
X_MAX, Y_MAX = 191, 380
WIDTH = X_MAX - X_MIN
HEIGHT = Y_MAX - Y_MIN
IMG_PATH = "data/PennFudanPed/PNGImages/FudanPed00002.png"

img = np.array(Image.open(IMG_PATH))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=FIGSIZE)
ax.imshow(img, aspect="equal")
ax.add_patch(plt.Rectangle(
    (X_MIN, Y_MIN), 
    WIDTH, 
    HEIGHT,
    fill=False,
    edgecolor="red",
    linewidth=LINEWIDTH
))
ax.text(
    X_MIN, 
    Y_MIN,
    "Walking person",
    bbox=dict(facecolor="blue", edgecolor='none', alpha=0.5),
    fontsize=FONTSIZE,
    color="white",
    horizontalalignment='left',
    verticalalignment='bottom',
)
plt.axis('off')
plt.tight_layout()
```

Unfortunately, I'm not able to keep it completely aligned (both vertically and horizontally) with the main bounding box. I can adjust manually the position but if I change the FIGSIZE, LINEWIDTH or FONTSIZE the text bounding box isn't aligned any more.

The result:

[image]

The image was taken [here](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~jshi/ped_html/).

How to get the bounding box of the text aligned with the rectangle?